# Trying to show all matches in a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

Currently I have this sell method, it checks if the name that has been entered by the user is in the linkedlist, if it is it will invoke the sell function from the product class.

```
private void sell() {
   int sellthis = -1;
   System.out.print("Name: ");
   String selloutput = In.nextLine();
   for (int y = 0; y < products.size(); y++){
     if (selloutput.equalsIgnoreCase(products.get(y).getName())){
        sellthis = y;
     }
    }
   if (sellthis < 0) {
       System.out.println("No such product");
    }
    else {

   System.out.println("Selling "+products.get(sellthis).getName());
   System.out.print("Number: ");
   int sellamount = In.nextInt();
   if (products.get(sellthis).has(sellamount)){
       cash.add(products.get(sellthis).sell(sellamount));
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Not enough stock");
  }
}
}
```

now I am trying to modify it so that if a user was to enter the value of Pen (case insensitive) it would say "Multiple matches found" and then list the matches that were found. I know my sell method seems to be a little medieval, sorry for that :p

sorry forgot to add that product contains these

```
public Product(String name, int stock, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.price = price;
}
```

the products I am using are as follows

```
    products.add(new Product("Whiteboard Marker", 85, 1.50));
    products.add(new Product("Whiteboard Eraser", 45, 5.00));
    products.add(new Product("Black Pen", 100, 1.50));
    products.add(new Product("Red Pen", 100, 1.50));
    products.add(new Product("Blue Pen", 100, 1.50));
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: How would I go about modifying sell so that if a user were to enter part of a product name it would either select that product or show a list of matching product names

Comment: I added the products to the latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to reach your goal you should :

1. test the equality as you do in your current code.
2. if it fails try the contains method to see if it's a partial match

if 1 is ok then return this product else if 2 is ok then increment a product compteur and add current product to the products candidate list.

```
for (int y = 0; y < products.size(); y++) {
        if (selloutput.equalsIgnoreCase(products.get(y).getName())) {
            sellthis += 1;
            candidates.add(products.get(y));
            break;
        }else if(products.get(y).getName().toUpperCase().contains(selloutput.toUpperCase())){
            sellthis += 1;
            candidates.add(products.get(y));
        }
    }
```

Comment: after trying to implement this, it works fine for all 3 pens, but when I attempt to use "Whiteboard" it instantly accepts the first instance (whiteboard marker). What did I do wrong?

Comment: i edited my answer as my code was a little at odd ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your product class looks like that:

```
public static class Product {

  private final String name;
  private final int stock;
  private final double price;

  public Product(String name, int stock, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

You could use the following code to find matching products and print them:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(new Product("Pen", 10, 1.0),
                                       new Product("Super Pen", 10, 2.0),
                                       new Product("Something Else", 10, 1.0));
  String userInput = "Pen";
  List<Product> matchingProducts = products.stream()
                                         .filter(p -> p.getName().toLowerCase()
                                                       .contains(userInput.toLowerCase()))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());

  System.out.println("Multiple matched found:");
  matchingProducts.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName()));
}
```

---

Of course this should just give you an idea. You could e.g. extract a method out of it.

---

This code uses Java 8 [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to filter out the matching products.

Comment: As a further improvement, you could abstract over the means of matching. This way there can coexist multiple ways to select products

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`String#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) on each product to see if the fragment entered is a partial match.  Something like this:

```
System.out.print("Name: ");
List<Product> matches = new ArrayList<>();
String selloutput = In.nextLine().toLowerCase();
for (int y=0; y < products.size(); y++) {
    String product = products.get(y).getName().toLowerCase();
    String pattern = ".*" + selloutput + ".*";
    if (product.matches(pattern)) {
        matches.add(products.get(y));
    }
}
```